# Internet Explorer 10 not accepting self signed Root CA

Tags: windows, linux, openssl, rsa

On a linux box, I have generated my Root CA and client certs using the following commands:

```
openssl genrsa -out rootCA.key 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 20000 -out rootCA.pem
openssl genrsa -out myserver.key 2048
openssl req -new -key myserver.key -out myserver.csr
openssl x509 -req -in myserver.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out myserver.crt -days 365 -sha256
```

I have installed the rootCA.pem file on a Windows 7 box successfully via the MMC console; no errors reported; the root cert is listed under the Trusted Root Certification Authorities area.

**When I go to visit the site, Internet Explorer 10 does not give me an option to "Continue to this website", but I have an RSA key of 2048 bits**.

To clarify the question, in case it is not clear by the title of the post: **"how can I get IE10 to accept a self signed root CA (generated using the method described) that has 2048 bit RSA?"**

Firefox on the Win7 box, and Chrome on a linux box, produce no issues, since I have added the rootCA.pem file to their list of trusted authorities.

However, Chrome and IE on the Win7 box both produce issues because they use the Windows cert authority lists.

The rootCA is good because both Chrome on linux and Firefox on windows have no issues with it.  And it is not related to the well-documented issue of having an RSA strength of less than 1024 bits.

I have also added the server to the list of 'trusted' sites in IE10, and still get the issue.

Multiple restarts involved, of course, per Windows SOP.

Actual contents of the rootCA:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 14306283983041559779 (0xc68a217c110d7ce3)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, ST=New York, L=New York, O=Widgets, Inc., CN=server1.widgets.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar 11 22:41:43 2016 GMT
            Not After : Dec 13 22:41:43 2070 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=New York, L=New York, O=Widgets, Inc., CN=server1.widgets.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:ef:2a:75:c1:e1:a4:07:c3:27:46:94:49:2f:2a:
                    27:0c:6d:33:d7:4c:84:ee:59:d0:83:18:10:c8:f9:
                    7e:8f:4e:19:ef:c3:6f:04:a7:a3:b2:9f:6f:03:de:
                    fb:9a:f6:17:4e:87:8c:29:93:9b:a3:52:63:19:29:
                    93:1e:cc:a0:22:fe:4e:7c:00:83:8f:82:c3:83:f1:
                    65:9d:2b:5e:b4:9e:4f:cc:29:62:a6:5f:5e:11:51:
                    99:2b:55:55:6b:17:13:6c:30:14:44:6f:a7:42:d0:
                    16:2b:02:76:5c:ae:76:4a:2b:60:b2:ea:1f:64:61:
                    09:8a:c6:9f:23:ef:85:82:c6:fb:f6:7d:ce:b4:c2:
                    a3:89:f8:98:79:f8:6a:df:6a:c5:44:75:41:f2:11:
                    7c:94:32:82:00:fd:ae:d4:ef:51:0f:7f:bc:2a:25:
                    d6:b3:53:fd:3f:13:21:7c:e0:d6:b7:87:5f:09:19:
                    79:7c:2f:cc:b1:c1:a2:49:bb:17:62:8f:e3:cd:db:
                    99:6a:2b:fc:d3:f8:9a:58:2d:0c:d0:bd:21:a1:2e:
                    64:f7:c0:84:7d:48:53:94:62:79:c4:bf:51:ba:04:
                    9e:1a:15:3e:a8:ec:3d:c2:c9:05:ed:67:dc:c0:ef:
                    6d:e0:fa:a7:0e:56:51:f7:7b:dd:1c:a4:88:f0:f4:
                    50:17
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                E9:F3:EC:16:D9:48:85:EC:29:E8:DB:8A:CD:1E:76:F2:37:9F:AA:F1
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:E9:F3:EC:16:D9:48:85:EC:29:E8:DB:8A:CD:1E:76:F2:37:9F:AA:F1

            X509v3 Basic Constraints:
                CA:TRUE
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         78:68:8d:e6:13:35:ba:60:05:7c:e5:c6:0e:2b:83:5c:3c:5d:
         ec:12:c2:6e:b5:a9:40:56:51:79:b2:50:75:5b:c5:88:05:71:
         27:3b:49:b0:de:16:9c:71:d2:9d:a2:84:6a:e3:91:4f:65:99:
         d3:e9:67:87:de:32:c9:d0:71:b1:8b:33:49:52:bd:be:63:bb:
         cf:7c:09:df:1e:a2:c4:62:c5:a3:74:b4:1e:13:b7:8a:7b:db:
         b7:76:36:d8:14:2c:07:b7:00:ba:9b:65:d3:22:9e:19:41:ee:
         b9:df:f5:bf:bf:76:8a:0f:68:b3:8a:09:69:ed:24:65:cc:95:
         1d:4f:05:91:20:9e:9c:7d:66:4f:57:2b:c4:c7:47:97:64:de:
         9c:10:93:30:8b:61:ea:49:5b:a7:98:fd:b7:cc:c8:8f:25:1c:
         9b:0a:49:b3:69:dc:20:dc:92:9a:01:a9:ed:9b:df:c6:65:c4:
         87:cb:07:f7:b1:53:f0:27:00:e5:d8:17:b7:0c:17:eb:6b:86:
         20:0a:97:dd:69:55:5e:02:cc:29:96:eb:64:3e:53:8c:4c:13:
         fb:10:01:e1:19:47:70:b8:54:34:b9:f1:fd:74:14:6f:e9:88:
         fb:18:13:99:31:21:f0:94:e0:b3:a1:92:ed:46:57:85:e6:33:
         b1:1d:5b:9f
```

Actual contents of the server certificate:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number: 11316521565276697315 (0x9d0c5c67f75d72e3)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, ST=New York, L=New York, O=Widgets, Inc., CN=server1.widgets.com  
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar 11 22:43:35 2016 GMT
            Not After : Mar 11 22:43:35 2017 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=New York, L=New York, O=Widgets, Inc., CN=server1.widgets.com 
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:c8:4d:ab:c9:62:b2:a8:ab:56:30:b7:26:da:d4:
                    1a:e5:9e:eb:77:81:3e:04:62:cd:a9:d7:65:1a:f4:
                    0b:8c:b0:c4:e4:c6:e4:4c:0e:43:3f:3f:a7:67:2d:
                    a2:4b:96:54:16:b0:cc:a2:91:f0:df:f9:6c:7f:1d:
                    49:bf:8d:0b:0a:ce:1c:0b:30:8a:2a:c6:85:07:b8:
                    4e:3d:a1:52:ab:cd:7e:fa:86:b2:21:e0:f3:90:f1:
                    78:a1:96:6e:53:17:82:bb:fd:10:48:cc:87:7f:4c:
                    22:d1:79:4f:77:fe:c7:48:9b:80:b3:c9:c6:46:87:
                    1d:01:6e:ae:47:14:fd:84:ac:bd:06:44:68:17:16:
                    b5:05:76:d4:e1:76:49:65:87:bd:05:61:05:3f:5b:
                    2c:7a:e5:43:a8:89:58:95:35:ec:68:6f:66:b8:29:
                    34:ff:77:cf:2b:26:99:0e:44:d3:94:24:bd:a2:fd:
                    ed:c3:df:f4:23:31:bf:48:0c:49:1a:95:07:11:29:
                    de:1f:c3:93:e2:99:60:a5:1e:e1:3e:a1:a2:f6:41:
                    17:f8:c5:e0:3f:98:87:b2:bb:07:9b:aa:73:b0:94:
                    c3:ab:27:bb:76:5c:57:f4:3e:36:02:80:92:af:ed:
                    e0:8e:f2:61:f6:22:ba:99:d4:35:a7:40:ac:4f:e0:
                    93:2b
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         c1:99:9b:b5:b2:d6:d9:c5:0d:1f:6d:db:73:34:f5:61:ea:b6:
         27:c5:d9:72:56:87:1a:60:8c:af:a4:b4:46:5c:b1:4d:cb:d6:
         21:a5:32:17:48:ea:ee:d6:cb:1e:78:cd:03:aa:16:57:09:cc:
         d2:d9:fa:b1:c1:7c:71:e2:cf:dd:32:e6:f0:cb:ca:1a:72:b0:
         79:9a:de:45:f9:f2:36:4c:d1:f4:78:e7:0c:b8:02:ac:71:07:
         d5:2a:22:90:62:ba:13:bc:2f:70:b2:b8:94:ce:e5:e3:46:b3:
         81:ac:05:25:05:76:d7:f5:74:f7:e8:11:05:ed:f0:22:1f:a5:
         a0:e7:81:2a:88:eb:5b:d3:1e:a5:bc:5b:2b:0e:b9:b1:c7:10:
         0a:d6:ec:23:a0:d5:4f:54:f8:08:e5:5a:9d:2c:3d:e6:bd:17:
         fa:7d:46:b2:33:96:5c:d7:84:47:a3:04:cf:be:e2:16:1f:f3:
         d9:df:1a:22:4a:80:ec:8b:30:72:62:2d:00:04:db:21:85:a8:
         57:7d:ff:f8:95:c9:6e:4a:d3:d8:32:f0:62:55:a1:b2:8e:88:
         dd:13:1c:ef:18:17:da:46:8b:3e:f7:cb:91:1a:84:2f:02:8a:
         8f:af:21:86:c3:f8:5c:67:ed:8d:c4:55:7c:7f:6b:98:ae:7b:
         f3:41:a7:e3
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When I go to visit the site, IE10 does not give me an option to "Continue to this website", but I have an RSA key of 2048 bits.  I need IE10 to recognize my self-signed root CA.  How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Please clarify this in your question.

Comment: OK, but I think the title of the post very clearly implies what my question is "ie not accepting self signed root CA with 2048 bit RSA"

Comment: If you have successfully installed the root CA certificate in your trust anchor store then you should not be prompted to **Continue to the website** - it should *just work*.  Maybe run `openssl x509 -noout -text -in <cert file>` on both the Root CA cert and the Server cert and post them in your answer?

Comment: @garethTheRed; that's exactly what I was expecting as well, it should just work, and it does just work on linux Chrome and W7 Firefox as mentioned; I have edited the answer to include the root CA and server certs

Comment: *"I have installed the rootCA.pem file on a Windows 7 box successfully via the MMC console..."* - what certificate store did you install your internal root certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work by creating a rootCA with a *different name* than the server identified in the server cert.  Instead of using `server1.widgets.com` as the CN in the rootCA, I used `Widgets Dev` as the CN.  I installed that rootCA in the Windows 7 box via the MMC console.  Then I created the server cert using `server1.widgets.com` as the CN and installed that on the server.

Note that I did not have to convert the rootCA from .pem format in order for the import to be successful on the Windows box.

Full contents of the altered rootCA below:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 11541727865071105011 (0xa02c7457b3ca73f3)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, ST=New York, L=New York, O=Widgets, Inc., OU=Widgets Dev, CN=Widgets Dev
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar 12 14:47:54 2016 GMT
            Not After : Dec 14 14:47:54 2070 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=New York, L=New York, O=Widgets, Inc., OU=Widgets Dev, CN=Widgets Dev
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:ef:2a:75:c1:e1:a4:07:c3:27:46:94:49:2f:2a:
                    27:0c:6d:33:d7:4c:84:ee:59:d0:83:18:10:c8:f9:
                    7e:8f:4e:19:ef:c3:6f:04:a7:a3:b2:9f:6f:03:de:
                    fb:9a:f6:17:4e:87:8c:29:93:9b:a3:52:63:19:29:
                    93:1e:cc:a0:22:fe:4e:7c:00:83:8f:82:c3:83:f1:
                    65:9d:2b:5e:b4:9e:4f:cc:29:62:a6:5f:5e:11:51:
                    99:2b:55:55:6b:17:13:6c:30:14:44:6f:a7:42:d0:
                    16:2b:02:76:5c:ae:76:4a:2b:60:b2:ea:1f:64:61:
                    09:8a:c6:9f:23:ef:85:82:c6:fb:f6:7d:ce:b4:c2:
                    a3:89:f8:98:79:f8:6a:df:6a:c5:44:75:41:f2:11:
                    7c:94:32:82:00:fd:ae:d4:ef:51:0f:7f:bc:2a:25:
                    d6:b3:53:fd:3f:13:21:7c:e0:d6:b7:87:5f:09:19:
                    79:7c:2f:cc:b1:c1:a2:49:bb:17:62:8f:e3:cd:db:
                    99:6a:2b:fc:d3:f8:9a:58:2d:0c:d0:bd:21:a1:2e:
                    64:f7:c0:84:7d:48:53:94:62:79:c4:bf:51:ba:04:
                    9e:1a:15:3e:a8:ec:3d:c2:c9:05:ed:67:dc:c0:ef:
                    6d:e0:fa:a7:0e:56:51:f7:7b:dd:1c:a4:88:f0:f4:
                    50:17
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                E9:F3:EC:16:D9:48:85:EC:29:E8:DB:8A:CD:1E:76:F2:37:9F:AA:F1
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:E9:F3:EC:16:D9:48:85:EC:29:E8:DB:8A:CD:1E:76:F2:37:9F:AA:F1

            X509v3 Basic Constraints:
                CA:TRUE
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         d0:e1:08:6b:4a:19:3e:29:06:27:fd:79:00:ed:a3:31:50:24:
         be:99:67:c7:a7:d3:4a:fa:6e:f0:a0:b6:97:67:b2:c0:ce:a9:
         4a:8c:d4:de:ee:be:9e:cb:53:33:c3:4e:ee:7a:21:e2:3d:5a:
         8d:f8:23:77:65:34:9f:f1:f7:1a:d3:c5:4b:b2:80:eb:06:22:
         4a:8c:94:86:b5:1b:db:2f:48:ab:55:5f:d3:7c:74:22:8e:dd:
         b1:64:1b:5a:ce:f5:ee:f3:10:d7:8e:28:d7:6a:35:e7:1f:9a:
         a9:9e:56:54:93:2e:a1:fb:e4:6c:88:57:56:73:f9:94:c4:96:
         bc:b7:08:4b:df:e8:80:a4:25:01:0e:07:c1:1b:68:d6:51:3f:
         5f:4e:0f:a9:22:f4:22:38:a8:d5:8b:fe:2a:19:2e:ed:0e:c0:
         c9:bd:b3:1a:49:a5:69:32:ad:54:2c:19:17:57:0d:9c:93:86:
         3e:51:77:e7:15:38:d3:90:13:7b:0e:db:75:45:1f:28:9d:ab:
         5a:90:3f:3d:6c:34:37:ca:e0:ac:fd:8e:33:03:42:00:03:c7:
         5b:9c:c1:ce:55:57:b4:67:f8:81:55:2c:9d:e6:2a:c9:44:74:
         22:4a:87:0f:fd:bf:a9:57:d5:88:79:b7:a9:a8:57:14:00:e3:
         16:af:0a:e1
```

Comment: That's how it's normally configured.  The CN would be something along the line of `Widgets Root CA`.  With your original configuration, the server CA was also self-signed (the Issuer and Subject were the same) and probably as the cause of CAPI's confusion.  It's also good to have the `Subject Key Identifier` and `Authority Key Identifier` (like you have in your Root cert) in your server cert as the AKI helps Windows find the next cert in the chain (the Root cert in this instance).

Comment: @garethTheRed Leaf cert *should* have AKI; SKI doesn't matter (but doesn't hurt). `req -x509` and `ca (default)` do these extensions by default, at least with the 'standard' config file; `x509 -req -CA/CAkey` requires explicit specification. Concur the name should be different and was (almost certainly) the problem.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - fair one. SKI is rather pointless on and end-entity certificate from a chain building point of view, but according to the [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.2) can be used to find certificates *containing a particular public key* - but I don't know whether there are any practical use of that in the wild.

Answer (score 2):

Your server certificate is malformed:

```
Version: 1 (0x0)
Serial Number: 11316521565276697315 (0x9d0c5c67f75d72e3)
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
Issuer: C=US, ST=New York, L=New York, O=Widgets, Inc., CN=server1.widgets.com
Subject: C=US, ST=New York, L=New York, O=Widgets, Inc., CN=server1.widgets.com
```

First, Version 1 is unusual, and it should be Version 3. You need Version 3 for Basic Constraints and `CA=false`.

Second, its not certified by your internal CA. Based on the Distinguished Names, it appears to be self signed.

Third, it its missing the server names in the *Subject Alternate Name (SAN)*. The browsers follow the [CA/Browser Baseline Requirements](https://cabforum.org/baseline-requirements-documents/), and all server names are placed in the SAN.

You never place a server name in the *Common Name (CN)*. The CN is displayed to the user, so it should be a friendly name "Widgets Web Service" (and the CA's CN would be "Widgets, Inc.").

Also see the following on Stack Overflow:

- [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639)
- [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27931596/608639)

Both answers examine the issuing rules and policies for the IETF and CA/B in detail. Both also explain how to create a certificates that are likely to be accepted by the largest number of user agents.

---

Regarding this statement:

> You never place a server name in the Common Name (CN).

The web is polluted with bad advice when it comes to the CN and SAN. Don't follow it.

Always follow:

- CN - friendly names ("Widgets Web Services")
- SAN - server names (widgets.example.com, ftp.example.com, mail.example.com, etc)

If you follow those two rules, most of the problems with browsers and certificates go away. The problems will usually reduce to trust (as opposed to unexplained name matching failures).

Answer (score 0):

Use "Manage user certificates" or "Manage computer certificates" (search control panel) and import it into "Trusted root certificates"

[image: Capture]

I think you can't directly import a .pem file try converting it into .crt or in PKCS12 if you are trying to import a key.

Comment: I converted the .pem to .crt with the same result, using the various tools (mmc console, etc.) to get the cert into the Trusted Root CA folder as your screenshot shows; same result - IE tells me there is a problem with the website's security certificate and does not offer the option to 'Continue to this website'

Comment: Check the key usages contained in your certificate mentions client authentication or sever authentication

Comment: also make sure the common name of the certificate matches the url in which it is deployed

Comment: Windows cert-import can handle PEM format, even the PEM-with-comments variant often used by OpenSSL, since XP/03 at least. *Root* cert should have KeyUsage for certSign (if present); *server* cert should have *KeyUsage* digSign and/or keyEnciph for RSA and *ExtendedKeyUsage* include serverauth if it is used at all, but OpenSSL-created certs usually don't use it.